# How to extract and use data values from an open $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, variables, echo, session-variables

My page accepts users through invitation codes to take surveys using UCCASS, and inspecting the session data goes as follows:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

> ```
> [invite_code_type] => alphanumeric
> [invite_code_length] => 10
> [priv] => Array
>     (
>         [37] => Array
>             (
>                 [2] => 1
>                 [3] => 1
>                 [name] => William
>                 [email] => will@william.com
>                 [uid] => 58
>             )
>     )
> )
> ```

How would I simply extract the current session's values for a welcome screen like this:

> "Hello William"

I tried the following without any luck:

```
echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['name'] . "<*br>";
```

Comment: how you're storing values ? can you show your code ? where you're putting the value is $_sessions variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that's how your taking value is not right.

But if 37 never changes, You can take it `$_SESSION['priv'][37]['name']`

But if key 37 will be varriable, then You have to loop all of them for example:

```
foreach($_SESSION['priv'] as $user)
{
    echo $user['name'];
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: 37 represents the survey's ID , so if a user takes survey ID 38 the loop works with your code, thinking ahead of the problem there

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION[priv][37]['name'] . "<*br>";
```

But i think your `[37]` is set there in a dynamic way so i suggest a `foreach` loop around `$_SESSION[priv]` so you can access all the keys beneath it and then you just get the `['name']` of each the same way i showed you and store it inside a new array which you are going to display it in your welcome message.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['priv'][37]['name'] . "<br/>";

foreach($_SESSION['prev'] as $key=>$value)
{
  foreach($values as $key=>$value)
     {
              echo $value['name'];
     }

}
```